# Equation to determine radius for a circle that should intersect a given point?

Tags: geometry, circles

Simple question. I tried Google but I don't know what search keywords to use.

I have two points on a $2D$ plane. **Point 1** $=(x_1, y_1)$ and **Point 2** $=(x_2, y_2)$.

[image: 1]

I'd like to draw a circle around Point 1, and the radius of the circle should be so that it intersects exactly with Point 2.

[image: 2]

What is the equation to determine the required radius?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's call the center of the circle: $P_1 = (x_1, y_1).\;$

Let $ P_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ be a point *on* circle. Then:

$r$: *radius* of the circle = *distance* between points $P_1$ and $P_2$, where

$$r = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$$

---

Any point $(x_i, y_i)$ satisfying the equation $(x_i - x_1)^2 + (y_i - y_1)^2 = r^2$ also lies on this circle.

Answer (score 3):

The radius is simply the distance between the two points.  So use the standard Euclidean distance which you should have learned.

Answer (score 3):

If $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ is the center, the radius will be $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$